# 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Add'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.Mvc;
 using System.Web.Optimization;
 using System.Web.Routing;

namespace Bloggers_Area
 {
     public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
     {
         public static object Filters { get; private set; }

        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection fiters)
         {
             Filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
         }

        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
         {
             routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                 "Default", // Route Name
                 "{controller}//{action}/{id}", //URL with parameters
                 new { Controller = "Login", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter Deafults
                 );
         }
             protected void Application_Start()
         {
             RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
             RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
         }
     }
 }
```

On this line :

```
filters.Add(new (HanldeErrorAttribute());
```

it keeps saying

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Add'  and no extension
>   method 'Add'  accepting a first argument  of type 'object' could be
>   found.

Can someone help please?

Comment: Poorly titled question. Should be more a specific.

Answer (score 0):

Currently inside your method `RegisterGlobalFilters` you refer to property `Filters` which is of type `object`. Instead you should refer to a method parameter `filters` (which starts from lowercase `f`) which is of type `GlobalFilterCollection`:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection fiters)
{
    // lowercase f in line below
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the property you declared is of type `object`:

```
public static object Filters { get; private set; }
```

And `object` indeed [does not contain a definition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kkx3h3c.aspx) for an `Add` method.  So just as the error says, you can't call a method which doesn't exist.

Perhaps you meant to call it on the `filters` which was passed to the method?:

```
filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
```

In which case you can probably also remove your `Filters` property entirely, since nothing would be using it.